# How to code the styles for the portrait only in the kindle fire device?

Tags: html, css, tabs

How to code the styles for the portrait only in the kindle fire device? please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation : portrait) and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx),(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    /* PORTRAIT:
    Kindle Fire HD 7
    */
}
```

Refer [this](https://gist.github.com/symblst/9412579) for more device related media queries.

Comment: the max-width is necessary here? I would like to apply the style to all the screen in the portrait view on the device.

Comment: You can remove or set new max-width in the media query.

Comment: while I am going to remove the max-width, it is fine on the browser but device does not support.

Comment: Can you tell which Kindle fire HD it is? Is it the 7" model or the 8.9" one?

Comment: The device name is: Kndle fire HDX 7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102877/discussion-between-amjs-and-sahil).